# Query Custom Post Type and sort by year

Tags: custom-post-types, archives

How do I create a page template were I can query all the posts from the Custom Post Type - let's say - "project" and order the results by year, displaying the year value at the beginning of each group .

Comment: You should probably first look into [templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Templates) and [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query), then try to narrow your question down a little. This is fairly broad. Also, search the site, there is at least one recent thread about displaying items with "year" headers.

Comment: I resolved the question using the Custom Post Type Archives plugin (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-archives/faq/) 

and this article: http://alex.leonard.ie/2009/08/27/wordpress-grouping-posts-by-monthyear/

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a page template to list the project post type, just go to /project/ and you'll have a full date ordered listing.

The template powering that page will be determined as follows:

- archive-project.php
- archive.php
- index.php

So create an `archive-project.php` in your theme. Using this you can specify to list only the titles.

Finally, on each post check to see if the year of the data has changed, and if so, echo the year out with whichever markup you please, and continue as usual, making note to echo the year out on the first project post.

Comment: Sounds like the right way! thanks, i'll try that out :)